# GET RESPONSE APDU Command

Tags: smartcard, apdu, smartcard-reader, contactless-smartcard

When I am tryi ng to get the response by using (A0 C0 00 00 1A)GET RESPONSE command,
I am getting 
SCardTransmit Failed! (80100008) The data buffer to receive returned data is too small for the returned data.
HOW TO RESOLVE THIS ERROR?

Comment: Please provide your code.

Comment: Wild guess: you need an additional 2 bytes for status word (SW1 SW2). I.e. you need buffer of 26 + 2 = 28 bytes. (( Side note: You really should spend more time writing your question if you want people to spend their time by answering it )) Good luck!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know the framework you are using. I assume you use native `WinSCard` or `PCSC Lite`. When using [SCardTransmit](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa379804(v=vs.85).aspx) you have to make sure parameter `pcbRecvLength` is big enough for your response to fit in.